# unable to resolve host on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

I SSH'ed into the server to do some updates, along the way I lost HTTP connectivity to the web site.

When I was updating, after encountering problems with yum, one of the things I read and tried, without really understanding was:

```
sudo dhclient
```

It's just about about the only thing that seemed to network related.

When I try the following from my PC:

```
curl -v http://sub.my-web-site.com/
```

the result:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: sub.my-web-site.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sub.my-web-site.com
```

When I try connect via the IP address, one of the virtual hosts seems to respond.

I have rebooted the instance a couple of times to no avail. I don't seem to recall changing any settings on the instance and it doesn't seem to be a part of a VPC.

The DNS is in route 53, and after rebooting, the public IP of the instance changed, so I updated in route 53 accordingly.
[image]

I tried dig from a couple of other servers, with slightly different results:

```
dig sub.my-web-site.com

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 56905
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sub.my-web-site.com. IN      A
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
my-web-site.com.        300     IN      SOA     01.dnsv.jp. hostmaster.dnsv.jp. 1531475254 3600 900 604800 300
;; SERVER: 202.167.237.16#53(202.167.237.16)

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 56905
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sub.my-web-site.com. IN      A
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
my-web-site.com.        60      IN      SOA     01.dnsv.jp. hostmaster.dnsv.jp. 1531475254 3600 900 604800 300
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2)
```

Those NXDOMAIN don't look good.

How can I get this resolved?

**EDIT:**

I'm speculating that there might be another cause, and that this was already a problem before I started the updates.  I have control over the sub-domains, but not the main domain and recently the main domain was re-pointed to a new site.  Could that have an effect?

Additional Edit:

I noticed upon a whois of the main site, I noticed the name servers were different, so I added the main site's NS to route 53 NS.  Still no go.

Comment: Can you give more details: you have an EC2 instance that is NOT the web server you want to connect to? Or those 2 servers are the same?

Comment: @Alexandre Fenyo - I have multiple servers running.  But the one in question is an EC2 instance running apache with multiple web sites (vhosts).  I hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: OK, it clarifies. Do you really dig sub.my-web-site.com or can you please give the real domain name? According to the NXDOMAIN status and the fact that the AUTHORITY section is not empty, it does not seem to be a problem with the  configuration of your EC2 instance but a problem relative to the DNS servers.

Comment: @Alexandre Fenyo - main domain is rise-corp.tokyo, one of the sub-domains is test.rise-corp.  Also, upon a whois, I noticed the name servers were different, so I added the main site's NS to route 53 NS.  Still no go.

Comment: OK, I think I've found the problem, I've added an answer that explains what it is and how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1- here is what is wrong with your DNS delegation using Route 53**

As you said in a comment, your main domain is rise-corp.tokyo and one of your subdomains is test.rise-corp.tokyo.

It appears that you have not registered the domain name rise-corp.tokyo  with Route 53:

```
% whois -h whois.nic.tokyo rise-corp.tokyo | grep Registrar | grep ID
Registrar IANA ID: 49
```

Your registrar ID is 49, but there are only two registrar IDs used by Route 53: 468 and 81, depending on the TLD (see IANA Registrar IDs public list: 81 is the registrar of a subcontractor of AWS, and 468 is directly registered to AWS).

So, as stated in Route 53 documentation:

> If you want to keep your domain name with the current registrar,
>   **inform the registrar to update the name servers for your domain to the
>   ones associated with your hosted zone**. If you’ve registered a domain
>   name with Route 53, your domain name will be automatically associated
>   with the correct name servers.

So, your domain has not been automatically associated with the correct name servers, because your main domain registrar is not among the two registrars used by Route 53.

Therefore, in that case, your should have followed the documentation: *If you want to keep your domain name with the current registrar, inform the registrar to update the name servers for your domain to the ones associated with your hosted zone.*

But it appears you have not:

```
% whois -h whois.nic.tokyo rise-corp.tokyo | grep 'Name Server'
Name Server: 01.DNSV.JP
Name Server: 02.DNSV.JP
Name Server: 03.DNSV.JP
Name Server: 04.DNSV.JP

% dig rise-corp.tokyo NS +short
03.dnsv.jp.
04.dnsv.jp.
01.dnsv.jp.
02.dnsv.jp.
```

None of these servers are AWS Route 53 name servers.

So adding test as a subdomain of rise-corp.tokyo in Route 53 will not make this subdomain being resolved. Because the servers serving requests for the tokyo TLD do not have the correct Route 53 NS resource records for rise-corp.tokyo.

**2- here is how to set up a correct delegation**

- Look at the Route 53 console,
- find the Route 53 name servers for your main domain,
- replace *.dnsv.jp by these servers in the console of the domain service provider on which you have bought rise-corp.tokyo.

After having done that, the following steps will happen automatically:

- this domain service provider will push the information to the registrar ID 49 named GMO Internet,
- GMO Internet will push the information to the tokyo registry that manages the servers serving requests for the tokyo TLD.

Note that there is a shortcut in this chain: GMO Internet is simultaneously a registrar (ID 49) for your main domain rise-corp.tokyo and the registry for the tokyo TLD. So both of the previous operations will be done at once.

**3- in-depth explanations**

Choosing which host is the DNS server for a domain and choosing the content of the zone file served by the chosen DNS server are two different things. I mean that the fact that the chosen DNS servers for the domain rise-corp.tokyo are *.dnsv.jp or are Route 53 does not change anything about the IP address of www.rise-corp.tokyo, www.test.rise-corp.tokyo, rise-corp.tokyo or test.rise-corp.tokyo. It simply means that the hostname-to-address map is stored in *.dnsv.jp servers or in Route 53 servers. The only difference is about which admin can change those hostname-to-address mappings.

When such a situation occurs, with two sets of people that need to manage parts of a single main domain, the common way to solve the problem is to delegate a subdomain. In your case, I understand that you only need to manage test.rise-corp.tokyo and sub domain names like mywebserver.test.rise-corp.tokyo, because the corresponding hosts are on EC2 and you want Route 53 to automatically set the mappings from their names to their public IPs. So, you can simply ask people that are responsible for rise-corp.tokyo to delegate test.rise-corp.tokyo to Route 53.

For this to be done, do not declare rise-corp.tokyo in Route 53 but only test.rise-corp.tokyo. Look at the console to find the Route 53 name servers running this domain and ask people that manage *.dnsv.jp to add some NS records for test.rise-corp.tokyo, pointing to the Route 53 servers for test.rise-corp.tokyo.

Finally, note that it is not so common, but two distinct teams *can* share resource records like name-to-address mappings ("IN A" ressource records) even if those mappings are at the same level, like host1.rise-corp.tokyo and host2.rise-corp.tokyo. To do that, the owner of rise-corp.tokyo delegates host1.rise-corp.tokyo to some name servers of the first team, using some "IN NS" resource record for host1.rise-corp.tokyo, and people of the first team create a zone file for host1.rise-corp.tokyo and add a "IN A" resource record to the IP address of host1.rise-corp.tokyo. The same thing is done for the 2nd team. This way, the IP address of host1.rise-corp.tokyo may be changed by the first team on their own, and the IP address of host2.rise-corp.tokyo may also be changed by the 2nd team on their own too: the IP address of host1 is only stored in the name servers managed by the first team, and the IP address of host2 is only stored in the name servers managed by the second team. No IP address for host1 or host2 is stored in the zone file for the main domain rise-corp.tokyo. The zone file for the main domain only stores the hostnames of the DNS servers of the two teams (and if those hostnames are under the corresponding sub-zones, there will be some GLUE records made of "IN A" resource records to the name servers of the two teams, but those IP addresses are not relative to the name-to-address mapping for host1 and host2). Using CNAME instead of NS records for host1.rise-corp.tokyo and other minor changes is another way to do the same thing.

As a conclusion, I'd say that many things and situations can be handled by the distribute DNS system. But for all of this to work correctly, proper coordination among all the partners is the key answer.

Comment: This makes sense. Another company did a redesign of the main site and are hosting it.  Making the switch last week.  However, I think they will need the *.dnsv.jp ns, to point at their new site.  Can I add the aws Ns's, and not replace them?  btw, I was informed of all of this, after the switch.

Comment: Choosing which host is the DNS server for a domain and choosing the content of the zone file served by the chosen DNS server are two different things. I mean that the fact that the chosen DNS servers for the domain rise-corp.tokyo are *.dnsv.jp or are Route 53 does not change anything about the IP address of www.rise-corp.tokyo, www.test.rise-corp.tokyo, rise-corp.tokyo or test.rise-corp.tokyo. It simply means that the hostname-to-address map is stored in *.dnsv.jp servers or in Route 53 servers. The only difference is about which admin can change those hostname-to-address mappings.

Comment: When such a situation occurs, with two sets of people that need to manage parts of a single main domain, the common way to solve the problem is to delegate a subdomain. In your case, I understand that you only need to manage test.rise-corp.tokyo and sub domain names like mywebserver.test.rise-corp.tokyo, because the corresponding hosts are on EC2 and you want Route 53 to automatically set the mappings from their names to their public IPs. So, you can simply ask people that are responsible for rise-corp.tokyo to delegate test.rise-corp.tokyo to Route 53.

Comment: For this to be done, do not declare rise-corp.tokyo in Route 53 but only test.rise-corp.tokyo. Look at the console to find the Route 53 name servers running this domain and ask people that manage *.dnsv.jp to add some NS records for test.rise-corp.tokyo, pointing to the Route 53 servers for test.rise-corp.tokyo.

Comment: I've added those comments and some more informations at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer.  When we get this all worked out, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

DNS resolution is unrelated to the server itself. The fact that you are receiving different responses from different servers suggests that there is a propagation delay.

Try again after a couple of hours and see whether all servers resolve the same way.

One method to avoid this delay is to assign an **Elastic IP Address** to the EC2 instance. This address will not change when an instance is stopped/started and it can also be instantly assigned to a different instance (with no propagation delay). You would point an `A` record from the DNS name to the Elastic IP address and then there would be no need to change it in future.

Comment: I setup an Elastic IP address and binded to the instance.  Still no go, still getting NXDOMAIN from dig the other servers.  Also, I added more info: I'm working with sub-domains, but don't have direct control to the main domain, which was recently changed to point to new site.  Thanks for the help.